# Efficient way to sort an array of numbers and string in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, sorting, integer

Input :

```
arr = [4,2,'b',5,'c','a',7]
```

Output:

```
[2,4,5,7,'a','b','c']
```

I can think of this :

```
int_arr = arr.select {|x| x.instance_of?(Integer)}.sort
str_arr = arr.select {|x| x.instance_of?(String)}.sort

int_arr + str_arr
```

Please suggest a efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to `partition` your array by those elements being Integer, to make sure they remain first and then sort the elements of each array:

```
[4,2,'b',5,'c','a',7].partition { |e| e.is_a?(Integer) }.flat_map(&:sort)
# [2, 4, 5, 7, "a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Don't forget `sort_by` which avoids the `a`/`b` thing.

Comment: One downside of the `to_s` approach is you get nonsense like `1, 11, 2, 20` and so on since they're sorted "ASCIIabetically". The `partition` approach is probably the best solution here.

Comment: Ups. Leaving just the partition way @3limin4t0r. As Cary has added something better with sort_by.

Comment: @SebastianPalma The other answer is also fine as long as you disclose it's boundaries. I'll remove my other comments since they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.sort_by { |e| [e.is_a?(Integer) ? 0 : 1, e] }
  #=> [2, 4, 5, 7, "a", "b", "c"] 

[22, 'efg', 0, 'abc', -4].sort_by { |e| [e.is_a?(Integer) ? 0 : 1, e] }
  #=> [-4, 0, 22, "abc", "efg"]
```

See [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by). `sort_by` performs pair-wise comparisons of 2-element arrays using the method [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). See especially the third paragraph of that doc.

The following could be used if, as in the example, the integers are single digits and the strings are single characters.

```
arr.sort_by(&:ord)
  #=> [2, 4, 5, 7, "a", "b", "c"]
```

See [Integer#ord](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-ord) and [String#ord](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-ord).